# Layer from geoserver not displayed in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

I installed the package with npm and set up localhost..I'm trying to display layer in map, but it dont show up.Please Help! I'm stuck.Not sure maybe the problem is in different ports,cus my application( localhost:1995) and my geoserver (localhost:8080) instance are running on separate  and use different ports.Someone to explain?

```js
import 'ol/ol.css';
import 'ol-layerswitcher/src/ol-layerswitcher.css';

import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import { transform } from 'ol/proj';
import LayerGroup from 'ol/layer/Group';
import LayerTile from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import SourceOSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import SourceStamen from 'ol/source/Stamen';
import TileImage from 'ol/source/TileImage';
import LayerImage from 'ol/layer/Image';
import SourceImageArcGISRest from 'ol/source/ImageArcGISRest';
import TileWMS from 'ol/source/TileWMS';
import ImageWMS from 'ol/source/ImageWMS';

import LayerSwitcher from 'ol-layerswitcher';

var OSM = new LayerTile({
    title: 'OSM',
    source: new SourceOSM(),
    type: 'base',
    visible: true
});
var googleLayerRoadmap = new LayerTile({
    title: "Google Road Map",
    source: new TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
    type: 'base'
});

var googleLayerSatellite = new LayerTile({
    title: "Google Satellite",
    source: new TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=pl&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
    type: 'base'
});
var Odjel = new LayerTile({
    source: new TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'cite:go_2',
        'TILED': 'true'},
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    }),
    title: "Odjel"
});
Odjel.setVisible(true);
var map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new LayerGroup({
            title: 'BASE LAYERS',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [OSM,googleLayerRoadmap,googleLayerSatellite
            ]
                }),
        new LayerGroup({
            title: 'Odjel',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [Odjel]
        }),
        new LayerGroup({
            title: 'LAYERS',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [
                new LayerImage({
                    // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                    title: 'Distrikti',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new SourceImageArcGISRest({
                        ratio: 1,
                        params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                        url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census_Boundaries/Census_Merged_Local_Authority_Districts_December_2011_Boundaries/MapServer"
                    })
                }),
                new LayerImage({
                    // A layer must have a title to appear in the layerswitcher
                    title: 'Kantoni',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new SourceImageArcGISRest({
                        ratio: 1,
                        params: {'LAYERS': 'show:0'},
                        url: "https://ons-inspire.esriuk.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census_Boundaries/Census_Merged_Wards_December_2011_Boundaries/MapServer"
                    })
                })
            ]
        })        
            ],
    view: new View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: transform([17.86339, 44.6054], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 6
    })
});
var layerSwitcher = new LayerSwitcher({
    groupSelectStyle: 'none' // Can be 'children' [default], 'group' or 'none'
});
map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OL Mapa</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>

  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in the console or invalid network requests (returining HTTP-code > 300)?

Comment: console is clear, network status code for those files is 200

Comment: but there is 304 status code for css and js file with GET

Comment: Are there any GetMap requests for this layer contain real pictures ?

Comment: Not sure what are u asking me,pretty new in this...But i tried simple code with source map link OL for library and not working still...In network window there is no pictures showed

Comment: Have you seen any network requests to your geoserver at all?

Comment: yes,there are few request in network Monitor and success status response

Comment: can you show an example of any of this requests?

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.3&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=%09cite%3Ago_2&TILED=true&projection=EPSG%3A3857&serverType=geoserver&format=image%2Fpng&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=626172.1357121654%2C5009377.085697312%2C1252344.2714243294%2C5635549.221409475
Request Method:GET
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Status Code:
200
Version:HTTP/1.1
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Hmm. Looks like a corrrect request. Did you view this layer in a geoserver admin site?

Comment: Yes, added layer from postgis (pgadmin) and then from layer preview copied..I checked in windows firewall settings, everything enabled for geosever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling CORS on your GeoServer and restarting it.  Since your OL app and GeoServer are on a different domain (port) this may explain your issue.  It is easy to do and would be a good troubleshooting step.

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#enable-cors

> The standalone distributions of GeoServer include the Jetty application server. Enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to allow JavaScript applications outside of your own domain to use GeoServer.
>
> For more information on what this does and other options see Jetty Documentation
>
> Uncomment the following  and  from webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```xml
<web-app>
  <filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```